# The specified CFC progress could not be found

Tags: coldfusion, statusbar, cfc

I have about 1 day of learning, until I need to be able to use Coldfusion (any detailed tutorial would be welcome).

I have 2 files (`t1.cfm` and `progress.cfc`) in ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot

### t1.cfm:

```
<CFIF IsDefined("session.STATUS")>
<cfset StructDelete(Session, "Status") />
</CFIF>

<html>
<head>
    <title>progressbar</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function startprogress(barname){
            ColdFusion.ProgressBar.show(barname);
            ColdFusion.ProgressBar.start(barname);
        }
        function onFin(){
            alert('Done');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <cfform>
    <p>
        <cfinput type="button" name="starter" value="start" onclick="startprogress('du')" />
        <cfprogressbar name="du" duration="10000" interval="1000" width="200" oncomplete="onFin" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <cfinput type="button" name="starter1" value="start" onclick="startprogress('du1')" />
        <cfprogressbar name="du1" bind="cfc:progress.getstatus()" interval="1000" width="200" oncomplete="onFin" />
    </p>
    </cfform>
</body> 
</html>
```

### progress.cfc:

```
component output="false"
{
    remote funktion getStatus(){
        str = StructNew();
        str.message = "blabla";
        if(NOT IsDefined("session.STATUS")){
            session.STATUS = 0.1;
            Sleep(200);
        }else if(session.STATUS LT 0.9){
            session.STATUS =session.STATUS +.1;
            Sleep(200);
        }else{
            str.message= "Done...";
            session.STATUS=1.0;
        }
        str.status =session.STATUS;
        return str;
    }
}
```

When I open `t1.cfm` it says:

The specified CFC progress could not be found.
The path to the CFC must be specified as a full path, or as a relative path from the current template, without the use of mappings.

I guess the problem is with `bind="cfc:progress.getstatus()"` but the tutorial I followed did the exact same thing and it worked there. What did I do wrong?

Comment: If you are new, start with something simpler.  Easycfm.com has starter level tutorials.  Also, when using cfc's do things in this order.  First, get the code to work in a .cfm file.  Then get it to work in a function, still in the .cfm file.  Then get it to work in a cfc file, which you call using coldfusion code such as createobject(), <cfobject>, or <cfinvoke>.  Then you are are ready to call it with javascript/ajax, which is what the bind keyword does.

Comment: Check out www.learncfinaweek.com. It's coldfusion taught by some of the best coldfusion developers out there. They avoid the CFUI tags you're using there because they are not particularly useful in real world situations. Jquery and other technologies are better at creating the UI/UX stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you've got a typo:

```
 remote funktion getStatus(){
```

should be:

```
 remote function getStatus(){
```

you put a K in function, rather than the C it'd need.

Comment: Thank you. it is still not working properly but it does something :)

Comment: your function is returning an object with two values - status & message - do you maybe need to map them to the cfprogressbar somehow? Are those the variable names it's expecting to be passed to it?

Comment: I don't think so. it is looping in the if statement instead of going in the else if